# Need An Event To Fire After Leaving A Grid Control Filter DevExpress

Tags: devexpress

Is there an event that fires after leaving a cell in a grid controls row filter?

The first row of my grid is a filter row, when I type something in the cell of and column in the filter row then select a row I want an event to fire.

What is happening is I have a lot of code in the `gridView1s` `FocusedRow` changed event, but when I use the filter then select the first row the `Focusedrow` event does not fire. If I select anything but the first first row returned the `Focusedrow` event fires and everything is fine, but I need to capture an event after you type something in a filter cell and select the first row in the grid.

Comment: Hi Nick, I am using XtraGrid 10.1.7 and the FocusedRowChanged event works fine for me.  Can you please give me more details about the problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: Get a grid populate it with data. Go to the filter row and type something in whatever cell that will filter the grid. Now select the FIRST row in the grid. The FocusedRow changed event doesnt fire.

Comment: Note....it will fire if you select any row other than the first row.

Comment: I am using GridControl 9.3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce this issue using XtraGrid 9.3.4. but to no avail.  Everything works as expected in my tests.  So, I would suggest that you create a new ticket in the [support center](http://devexpress.com/support/center) and upload a sample project.  We will find the cause of the issue and let you know how to resolve it.